# pass model to view and back to a new controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have made a password reset controller that takes in a GUID querystring. As you can see in the below code, my controller checks if the GUID value exists in my db, whereafter it returns `user` to the view with the attributes name and userId.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RetreivePass(string ac)
{
    MySqlContext db = new MySqlContext();
    PwRetreival PwRetreival = new PwRetreival();
    Users user = new Users();

    if (db.PwRetreival.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Token == ac) != null)
    {
        PwRetreival.uId = db.PwRetreival.Where(u => u.Token == ac).Select(u => u.uId).First();
        var Attributes = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == PwRetreival.uId).Select(u => new { u.Name, u.UserId }).FirstOrDefault();
        user.Name = Attributes.Name;
        user.UserId = Attributes.UserId;
        return View(user);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

In my view, it looks like this:

```
<p>Hello @Model.Name</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>Change password</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Password)
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </p>
}
```

And finally, upon submit, i call this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string RetreivePass(Users model)
{
   //Some code here 
}
```

Unfortunately, my issue is, that the parameters (Name & UserId) are not returned with the model to the controller on submit. Therefore i only have the password, which i can't use for anything, because i cant tell my controller where to put the updated password.

Am i missing something??

For convenience, my models are as follows:

```
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
}

public class PwRetreival
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int uId { get; set; } //FK to Users.UserId
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include the name into the form as some input parameter (hidden if the user is not supposed to modify it):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>Change password</p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.UserId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Password)
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </p>
}
```

So basically all parameters that you hope to retrieve when you postback must be included either as input fields inside your form or as query string parameters.

Of course you realize that a hidden field or a query string parameter can be modified from the outside making it quite insecure. Anyone knowing the `UserId` of another user could trigger a password reset for him. In order to make a secure password reset functionality you might need some cryptography involved. For example you could use a symmetric cryptographic algorithm to encrypt the `UserId` and send the encrypted value to the client in the password reset email. Then when the form is POSTed back the encrypted value could be decrypted on the server  to extract the original client id and the new password. If the encrypted value has been tampered with you will know that immediately.

Another approach would be to generate some token on the server which will be associated with your user and stored in your backend. Then send this token to the client in the password reset email and when POSTed back you will know who the original user was by looking at your backend. It is also a good idea to sign this token using a server secret to ensure that it hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: But is that safe to do? Ultimately, this hidden parameter (userId) is supposed to decide, which password attribute is changed in the db.

Comment: No of course that it is not safe. I have updated my answer to mention that. In order to make a password reset functionality you will need some cryptography.

Comment: i just realized. How would i do it otherwise then? i obviously want to build this in a responsible fashion.

Comment: You could encrypt the user id using some symmetric cryptographic algorithm and then pass the encrypted value form the client and decrypt it on the server.

Comment: I get your point! But really, cant it be done in a smarter way?

Comment: Yes of course, using symmetric cryptography or some sort of shared token.

Comment: This is a good solution for anything but a password...shouldnt be sending passwords to the browser encrypted or not

Comment: @raykrow, as soon as you use HTTPS, passwords will not be sent in clear text between the client and the server and thus you will be protected against man-in-the-middle attacks. The issue that the OP is having here is knowing who the user that is trying to reset his password is.